# how to create temporary tokens django

Tags: python, django, token

I have found that we can make temporary tokens with this in Django :

```
pip install Django-rest-framework-temporary-tokens
```

but I don't know how to use this method. does anybody know how to use this or any other way to make temporary tokens in Django ??

Answer (score 3):

I have not worked with this library but I think this should be the place where you should begin with.

[django-rest-framework-temporary-tokens documentation](https://bitbucket.org/kbktech/django-rest-framework-temporary-tokens)